# Simple cycle removing algorithm for a BGL graph

Tags: algorithm, boost, graph, cycle

My problem should be pretty simple, given a graph (BGL adjacency_list) is there a simple algorithm to remove cycles? My first attempt was to use the DFS visitor to detect an edge that'd close the cycle and then remove it but I was unable to implement it correctly.

Any suggestions? Code samples would be best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost is great. It has a `depth_first_search` method that accepts a visitor. [You can see more information about it here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/doc/DFSVisitor.html).

All you need to do is implement a visitor like this:

```
class CycleTerminator : public boost::dfs_visitor<> {
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
    void back_edge(Edge e, Graph& g) {
        //implement
    }
};
```

remembering of course that a back edge is an edge that closes a cycle in the graph.

Comment: Nice, clean and elegant. I'll accept this one, but I figured out that I have to actually remove all edges of the cycle. I'll open a new question for that because it actually changes the question ^^

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple DFS, as you said. Each time you come to a node you visited before, there's a cycle. Just remove the last edge.

A pseudocode in no particular language.

```
void walk(current_node, previous_node)
   if visited[current_node]
      remove edge between current_node and previous_node
      return
   end

   visited[current_node] = true
   for (each adjacent node) 
      walk(adjacent_node, current_node)
   end
end
```