# How to find closed loops in graph networks

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa, loops, graph

I have an undirected graph network made of streets and crossings, and I would like to know if there is any algorithm to help me finding closed loops, ie places where I can put buildings.
Any help appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments to my earlier answer:

It seems the graphs are all undirected and planar, i.e. can be embedded in a 2D plane without crossing edges, *and* one such embedding is given. This embedding will partition the plane. E.g. a figure 8 partitions the plane in three: two "inner" areas and an infinite outer area. An alternative view is that all edges of a node are cyclically ordered. (This is the essential part that allows us to apply graph theory)

A partition is necessarily enclosed by a cycle, but not all cycles may partition a single area. In the trivial case of a figure 8, though, all three areas are directly associated with a distinct cycle.

The input graph can generally be simplified. Some nodes may have only a single edge; they can't contribute to the partitioning and can be removed along with the edge. Other nodes have two edges connecting distinct nodes. Here, the node and the two edges can be replaced by a direct edge connecting the neighbors. I.e. a figure 8 graph can be simplified to two nodes and three edges between them. (This is not a necessary step but helps computation).

Now, each vertex will have two areas to either side (since they're undirected, "left and right" aren't obvious distinctions). So, for `|V|` vertices, we need to consider `2 * |V|` sides. They're in general not distinct. Two adjacent edges (connected to the same node) may border the same area, if they're also adjacent in the cyclic order of edges of that node. Obviously, for nodes with only two edges, the two edges share both areas (which is why we'd eliminated them in the previous step). For nodes with three edges, any two edges share *at least* one area.

So, here's how to enumerate those areas: Assign a sequential number to all edges and vertices. Assign a direction to each edge so it runs from the lower-numbered edge to the higher. Start with vertex 1, right side, and number this area 1. Trace the boundary edges of this area, assigning the same number 1 to the appropriate sides of its boundary edges. You do this by taking at each node the next adjacent edge in counter-cyclical order. When you get back to your starting point, you know all edges bounding area 1.

You then check the left edge of the first vertex. If it's not part of area 1, then it's area 2, and you apply the same algorithm. Next, check vertex 2, right side and left side, etc. Each time you find an edge and a side that's unnumbered yet, assign the next area number and trace the edges of the newly founded area.

There's a slight problem with determining which area number corresponds to infinity. To see this, take a simple () graph: two edges, two nodes, and two areas (inside and outside). Due to the random numbering of edges and vertices, outside may end up as either 1 or 2. That's unavoidable; in graph theory there's no distinction between inside and outside.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard function in the Boost Graph library. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842790/simple-cycle-removing-algorithm-for-a-bgl-graph/4842867#4842867) for details.

Comment: Thanks, however I have the impression that this standard function will give me all the loops. For example a square with a line crossing it will be seen as 3 loops (above rectangle, below rectangle and the whole square), when I would be only looking at both rectangles. Am I guessing right ? Thanks.

Comment: Eh, in standard graph theory, your answer (both rectangles) doesn't make sense. You may think of your example as a figure 8, but that's just one of the visual representations. Consider that graph as 7 pieces of string, notted together at 6 points.If you pick it up and throw it in the air, it will land in another position, but it's still the same graph with the same strings and same knots. Even while in the air it's the same. There are many kinds of "special" cycles in graph theory, e.g. cycles that do not coincide with any other cycle, but I can't see the mathematical basis of your criterium.

Comment: PS: Have a peek at http://url3.tk/untangle/ - it's a graph game that may shed some light on (planar) graph theory. In particular, note that you _cannot_ change the graph. The edges and nodes are fixed.

Comment: Thanks MSalters, I understand your point... and the game :-) However I maybe expressed myself not sufficiently, my network is indeed composed of 2 rectangles having a side in common, and whose points are geographically not moveable. Maybe I shouldn't have called it a graph/network then... Is there kind of algorithm compatible with what I am looking for ?