# Graph: extract faces

Tags: graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find closed loops in graph networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022082/how-to-find-closed-loops-in-graph-networks)

I have a question regarding graphs. I need to extract all the faces of a graph (imagine a street network where I have to extract all the "blocks"). If you think of a typical checkerboard pattern (e.g. Manhattan) most faces have 4 edges und 4 nodes, but the whole thing should work for other possibilities too (where a face has more than 4 edges for instance).

How can I do that? I thought of diverse things and tried to google it but I did not found a satisfying answer.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for all cycles of length `n`.  Modulo certain conditions, the set of all such cycles will correspond to the "faces" you seek.

If you use this approach, it will become significant if your graphs are directed or not.