# Find all partitions of a plane created by a set of lines

Tags: python, matlab, math, wolfram-mathematica, computational-geometry

I have a set of lines (linear functions of the form y = mx + b) (120 of them!) and if I graph them all, then they partition the R^2 plane. The lines do not necessarily go through the origin.

What is the most efficient way to find all partitions created by a set of such lines? Personally, I'm having a hard time coming up with any way at all, let alone an efficient one. To be more clear, I include the following image of just 4 lines:[image: ste of lines]

An example of a partition would be the set `{(x,y)| -30x+28<= y && 60x+2 <= y <= 90x+7}` , which is the partition created by the red, yellow and green lines in the first quadrant. Another example would be `{(x,y)|y <= -30x+28 && 5x+3 <= y <= 60x+2}`, which is the triangle in the first quadrant that is bounded by the blue, red and green lines.

An example of a *non* partition would be `{(x,y)|5x+3 <= y <= -30x+28}`, which is the set bounded by the green line above and the blue line below. This is not a partition because there are several partitions contained within it (like the second set above, for instance), or overlapping it. The set `{(x,y)|5x+3 <= y <= -30x+28 && 90x+7 <= y}`, however, would be a partition.

The desired output would be a complete list of such sets:
`{(x,y)|y <= -30x+28 && 5x+3 <= y <= 60x+2},{(x,y)| -30x+28<= y && 60x+2 <= y <= 90x+7}...` etc. They don't have to be given in this notation, of course.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem, and so, unfortunately, can't provide much in the way of what I have tried. Ideally, I would like to do this in R, Python, Mathematica or MATLAB, but I'm open to any option at this point.

**EDIT:** Since there seems to be an issue with notation, I'll clarify a bit. It is sufficient to simply get a list of conditions on points, such that all points meeting that condition would exactly define a partition. For example, a long list of intersections, would be fine: `y <= 5x+3 && y >= 90x+7 && y<= -30x+28` is perfectly good output defining a partition. The desired output, of course, is a complete list of such partitions (as defined above).

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Desired output is simply a list of such sets, aka a list of partitions. I have added this to the question, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps Clipper library provides needed functionality (I tried only polygons, not lines, but library approach considers line as open polygon). It has some kind of Python binding. http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php

Comment: Reiterating the need for desired output. This is simply a matter of converting several borders into polygons. See here for example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23931/how-to-intersect-lines-and-polygons-in-r

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022082/how-to-find-closed-loops-in-graph-networks

Comment: This problem is known as the "Arrangement of Lines" and has been extensively studied. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_of_lines

Comment: Since no one has mentioned it yet, you might want to look into qhull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution in Mathematica.  The method involves finding the line intersection points, the line fragments and then the partitions, while keeping track of which lines the points are connected to.

```
y[1] = 5 x + 3;
y[2] = 90 x + 7;
y[3] = -30 x + 28;
y[4] = 60 x + 2;

findpoints[n_] := Module[{},
  xp = DeleteCases[{{First[#1], First[#2]},
       Solve[Last[#1] == Last[#2], x]} & @@@
     DeleteCases[
      Tuples[Array[{#, y[#]} &, n], 2],
      {{x_, _}, {x_, _}}], {_, {}}];
  yp = y[#[[1, 1]]] /. #[[2, 1]] & /@ xp;
  MapThread[{#1, {#2, #3}} &,
   {xp[[All, 1]], xp[[All, 2, 1, 1, 2]], yp}]]

xyp = findpoints[4];

{xmin, xmax} = Through[{Min, Max}@
    xyp[[All, 2, 1]]] + {-0.7, 0.7};

outers = Flatten[Array[Function[n,
     MapThread[List[{{n, 0}, {##}}] &,
      {{xmin, xmax}, y[n] /.
    List /@ Thread[x -> {xmin, xmax}]}]], 4], 2];

xyp = Join[outers, xyp];

findlines[p_] := Module[{},
  pt = DeleteCases[
    Cases[xyp, {{p[[1, 1]], _}, _}], p];
  n = First@Cases[pt,
     {_, First@Nearest[Last /@ pt, Last[p]]}];
  {{First[p], First[n]}, {Last[p], Last[n]}}]

lines = Map[findlines, xyp];

(* boundary lines *)
{ymin, ymax} = Through[{Min, Max}@outers[[All, 2, 2]]];
{lbtm, rbtm, ltop, rtop} = {{xmin, ymin},
   {xmax, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}};
xminlines = Partition[Union@Join[{ymin, ymax},
      Cases[xyp, {_, {xmin, _}}][[All, 2, 2]]], 2, 1] /.
   x_Real :> {xmin, x};
xmaxlines = Partition[Union@Join[{ymin, ymax},
      Cases[xyp, {_, {xmax, _}}][[All, 2, 2]]], 2, 1] /. 
   x_Real :> {xmax, x};
lines2 = Join[Last /@ lines, xminlines, xmaxlines,
   {{lbtm, rbtm}}, {{ltop, rtop}}];

ListLinePlot[lines2]
```

[image]

```
(* add vertex points *)
xyp2 = Join[xyp, {
   {{SortBy[Cases[outers, {_, {xmin, _}}],
       Last][[-1, 1, 1]], -1}, ltop},
   {{SortBy[Cases[outers, {_, {xmax, _}}],
       Last][[-1, 1, 1]], -1}, rtop},
   {{SortBy[Cases[outers, {_, {xmin, _}}],
       Last][[1, 1, 1]], -1}, lbtm},
   {{SortBy[Cases[outers, {_, {xmax, _}}],
       Last][[1, 1, 1]], -1}, rbtm}}];

anglecalc[u_, v_] := Mod[(ArcTan @@ u) - (ArcTan @@ v), 2 π]

getlineangles[] := Module[{},
  (* find the angles from current line
     to all the linked lines *)
  angle = Map[
    anglecalc[{c, d} - {g, h}, # - {g, h}] &,
    union = DeleteCases[Union@Join[
        Last /@ Cases[lines2, {{g, h}, _}],
        First /@ Cases[lines2, {_, {g, h}}]],
      {c, d}]];
  Sort[Transpose[{N@angle, union}]]]

getpolygon[pt_, dir_] := Module[{},
  Clear[p];
  p[n = 1] = {{a, b}, {c, d}} = pt;
  (* find the angles from vector (0, -1) or (0, 1)
     to all the linked lines *)

  angle = Map[anglecalc[If[dir == 1, {0, -1}, {0, 1}], # - {c, d}] &,
    union = Union@Join[
       Last /@ Cases[lines2, {{c, d}, _}],
       First /@ Cases[lines2, {_, {c, d}}]]];
  lineangles = Sort[Transpose[{N@angle, union}]];
  (* next point *)
  p[++n] = {{e, f}, {g, h}} = First@
     Cases[xyp2, {_, lineangles[[1, 2]]}];

  While[Last[p[n]] != Last[p[1]],
   lineangles = getlineangles[];
   (* reset first point *)
   {{a, b}, {c, d}} = {{e, f}, {g, h}};
   (* next point *)
   p[++n] = {{e, f}, {g, h}} = First@
      Cases[xyp2, {_, lineangles[[1, 2]]}]];

  Array[p, n]]

len = Length[xyp];

polygons = Join[Array[(poly[#] = getpolygon[xyp[[#]], 1]) &, len],
   Array[(poly[# + len] = getpolygon[xyp[[#]], 2]) &, len]];

graphics = DeleteDuplicates /@ Array[Last /@ poly[#] &, 2 len];

sortedgraphics = Sort /@ graphics;

positions = Map[Position[sortedgraphics, #] &,
    DeleteDuplicates[sortedgraphics]][[All, 1, 1]];

unique = poly /@ positions;

poly2 = unique[[All, All, 2]];

poly2 = Delete[poly2,
   Array[If[Length[Intersection[poly2[[#]],
         Last /@ Take[xyp2, -4]]] == 4, {#}, Nothing] &,
    Length[poly2]]];

len2 = Length[poly2];

poly3 = Polygon /@ Rest /@ poly2;

Array[(centroid[#] = RegionCentroid[poly3[[#]]]) &, len2];

Show[Graphics[Array[{ColorData[24][#],
     poly3[[#]]} &, len2], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],
 Graphics[Array[Text[#, centroid[#]] &, len2]]]
```

[image]

```
unique2 = Extract[unique,
   Flatten[Position[unique[[All, All, 2]], #] & /@ poly2, 1]];

makerelations[oneconnection_, areanumber_] := Module[{i},
  If[Intersection @@ oneconnection == {} ||
    (i = First[Intersection @@ oneconnection]) < 1,
   Nothing,
   centroidx = First[centroid[areanumber]];
   linepos = y[i] /. x -> centroidx;
   relation = If[linepos < Last[centroid[areanumber]],
     " >= ", " < "];
   string = StringJoin["y", relation, ToString[y[i]]]]]

findrelations[n_] := Module[{},
  areanumber = n;
  onearea = unique2[[areanumber]];
  connections = Partition[First /@ onearea, 2, 1];
  strings = DeleteDuplicates@
    Map[makerelations[#, areanumber] &, connections];
  StringJoin["Area ", ToString[areanumber],
   If[areanumber > 9, ": ", ":  "],
   StringRiffle[strings, " &&\n         "]]]

Show[Plot[Evaluate@Array[y, 4], {x, -1, 1.5},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", Axes -> None],
 Graphics[Array[Text[#, centroid[#]] &, len2]]]

Column@Array[findrelations, len2]
```

[image]

> ```
> Area 1:  y >= 28 - 30 x &&
>          y < 3 + 5 x
> Area 2:  y >= 2 + 60 x &&
>          y >= 28 - 30 x &&
>          y < 7 + 90 x
> Area 3:  y < 28 - 30 x &&
>          y < 7 + 90 x &&
>          y < 2 + 60 x &&
>          y < 3 + 5 x
> Area 4:  y >= 3 + 5 x &&
>          y >= 28 - 30 x &&
>          y < 2 + 60 x
> Area 5:  y < 3 + 5 x &&
>          y >= 2 + 60 x &&
>          y < 7 + 90 x
> Area 6:  y < 28 - 30 x &&
>          y >= 2 + 60 x &&
>          y >= 3 + 5 x &&
>          y < 7 + 90 x
> Area 7:  y < 28 - 30 x &&
>          y >= 3 + 5 x &&
>          y < 2 + 60 x
> Area 8:  y < 28 - 30 x &&
>          y >= 7 + 90 x &&
>          y >= 3 + 5 x
> Area 9:  y < 2 + 60 x &&
>          y >= 7 + 90 x
> Area 10: y >= 28 - 30 x &&
>          y >= 7 + 90 x
> Area 11: y < 3 + 5 x &&
>          y >= 7 + 90 x &&
>          y >= 2 + 60 x
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Finding the number of partitions follows this formula (when no 3 or more lines intersect at the same point - this assumption is carried throughout this post):

```
num_partitions = (n_lines * (n_lines + 1) / 2 ) + 1
```

An explanation can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180324135000/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54459.html), and another one [there](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/LinesDividePlane.shtml).

> The desired output would be a complete list of such sets:
> `{(x,y)|y <= -30x+28 && 5x+3 <= y <= 60x+2}, {(x,y)| -30x+28<= y && 60x+2 <= y <= 90x+7}...`
> etc... They don't have to be given in this notation, of
> course.

#### The lack of a precise notation is a handicap here.

Below is my back of the envelop attempt. As you see, it is possible to identify the numbered areas based on their relative positioning to each line.
There are 5 empty sets, which won't be the same if the lines ordering changes.
***It would probably be easier to partition a set of points on the plane with lines***, trying to determine which point belongs to which set; in such a case, exploring the `2^n` potential partitions, and returning their content would be easy. (easier than trying to find a good notation for identifying an abstract set)

[image]

This doesn't fully answer your question, but may be a good strating point for someone able/willing to push this further.
Here is a note on [partitioning a set of points with two lines in the plane.](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Emegiddo/pdf/2lines.pdf)
it is a different problem, but some of its approach could be useful.

#### other approaches:

Identify the polygons formed by the line segments, calculate a convex hull, determine if a point is in that hull.

Comment: Some nice thoughts in here, but with 120 lines (like the OP has) your 2^n partitions is O(10^36), and could be pretty expensive to explore!

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I think there is a better way hidden in this approach: If we go the road of identifying points in each region, which is far easier that defining what a region is, we can likely (although I have no proof) scan this in `O(num_points * num_partitions * log(max(num_points, num_partitions)))`. In any event, if you are going to enumerate the regions, which the OP intends to do, you have no choice but to go through every one of them.

Comment: You had of course to check first that not three lines go through the same point - the OP doesn't mention that this is a given. Recursive approaches with partition sets fast get out of hand, so I assume, scanning the plane is a good idea.

Comment: good point; I assumed that was the case. I added a note to mention this assumption, thanks for the assist @Piinthesky.

Comment: Unfortunately three or more lines do intersect at a point in several cases. The lines are sometimes pretty close together and there’s a 120 of them, so it’s unavoidable in my situation.

Comment: Yes, it is not a simple problem to solve (multiple lines intersecting at the same point is not so hard to handle though); but it is an interesting one... upon reflecting on the matter, my preference now would be to go the way of polygons (which would all be convex, and disjoint), and testing if a point is contained within one... But that means reformulating your problem as "identifying which points on a plane are contained within which polygon, delimited by intersecting lines.

Comment: 4 lines forming a rectangle breaks the formula (9 vs 11)

Comment: hehe, yeah, computational geometry is a minefield of special and degenerate cases. None of these lines should be parallel to any other.

Comment: No parallels, no more than two lines intersecting at the same point.

Answer (score 2):

Full Matlab solution. 120 lines 7021 partitions, in 0.4 seconds raw calculation (+2 seconds for drawing).

Final.

```matlab
clear
tic
%rng(15) % fix rng for debug
NLines=9;
DRAW_FINAL_POLY= true==true ; %false true
DRAW_FINALTEXT= true==true ; %false true
DRAW_LINES= false==true; %false true
DRAW_DEBUG= false==true; %false true

% part a - generate lines
NORM_EPS=1e-10;
Lines=10*(rand(NLines,4)-0.5); %(x1,y1,x2,y2)
Color=rand(NLines,3);
Lines(1,:)=[-10,0,+10,0];% x axis if we want to add asix as lines
Lines(2,:)=[0,-10,0,+10];% y axis
Color(1,:)=[1,0,0];% x axis red
Color(2,:)=[0,1,0];% y axis green
Color(3,:)=[0,0,1];% third blue

AllPairs=sortrows(combnk(1:NLines,2));
NPairs=size(AllPairs,1);
[px,py,isok,d] = LineIntersection(Lines(AllPairs(:,1),:) , Lines(AllPairs(:,2),:));
% draw lines and intersections
figure(7); cla; ax=gca;axis(ax,'auto');
if DRAW_LINES
    for iline=1:size(Lines,1)
        line(ax,Lines(iline,[1 3]),Lines(iline,[2 4]),'LineWidth',2','Color',Color(iline,:)); %draw partial line defined by points x1y1x2y2
    end
    for i=1:NPairs %extraploate line to intersection point
        iline1=AllPairs(i,1);
        iline2=AllPairs(i,2);
        line(ax,[Lines(iline1,[1]),px(i)],[Lines(iline1,[2]),py(i)],'LineWidth',2','Color',Color(iline1,:));
        line(ax,[Lines(iline2,[1]),px(i)],[Lines(iline2,[2]),py(i)],'LineWidth',2','Color',Color(iline2,:));
    end
    line(ax,px,py,'LineStyle','none','Marker','*','MarkerSize',8,'Color','g');%draw intersection points
    for i=1:NPairs
        text(px(i)+0.2,py(i)+0.2,sprintf('%d',i),'FontSize',14,'Color','c')
    end
end

% part b - find regions
% 1 for each line sort all its intersections
SortIntr=cell(1,NLines); %(if no parallel lines than NintrsctnsPerline = NLines-1)
IpairiIdx1=cell(1,NLines);
IpairiIdx2=cell(1,NLines);
IpairiIdxI=cell(1,NLines);
for iline=1:NLines
    [idx1,idx2]=find(AllPairs==iline);
    intr=[px(idx1),py(idx1)];
    [~, Isortedintr]=sortrows(intr.*[1,1]); %sort by increaing x y. (prepare clockwise travers)
    SortIntr{iline}=intr(Isortedintr,:);
    IpairiIdx1{iline}=idx1(Isortedintr);
    IpairiIdx2{iline}=3-idx2(Isortedintr); %keep indexes of second line
    IpairiIdxI{iline}=Isortedintr;
end
% 2 traverse from every point and find next closest intersctionn
% we go clockwise x+x-y
PointsInPartition={};
SolIndexInPartition={};
LineIndexInPartition={};
Line4PointsInPartition={};
VisitedSequence=false(NPairs,NPairs); %skip same sequence
count_added=0; count_skipped=0;

for iline=1:NLines
    for ipoint_idx=1:length(SortIntr{iline})-1 %cant start from last point in line
        ipoint=SortIntr{iline}(ipoint_idx,:);
        if DRAW_DEBUG
            delete(findall(ax,'Tag','tmppoint'));
            line(ax,ipoint(1),ipoint(2),'LineStyle','none','Marker','O','MarkerSize',12,'Color','r','tag','tmppoint');%draw intersection points
        end
        current_line=iline;
        isol_idx=IpairiIdx1{current_line}(ipoint_idx);
        current_p_idx=ipoint_idx;
        current_l_next_p_idx=current_p_idx+1;
        next_line=AllPairs(IpairiIdx1{current_line}(current_l_next_p_idx), IpairiIdx2{current_line}(current_l_next_p_idx));
        % next_point_idx = find(IpairiIdx1{current_line}(next_point_idx)==IpairiIdx1{next_line});
        sol_idx_list=[isol_idx]; 
%       if ismember(isol_idx,[7,8,12]),keyboard;end
        point_list=[ipoint];
        line_list=[iline];
        while next_line~=iline
            if DRAW_DEBUG
                delete(findall(ax,'Tag','tmpline'));
                line(ax,Lines(current_line,[1 3]),Lines(current_line,[2 4]),'LineWidth',4','Color',[ 0,0,0 ],'Tag','tmpline');
                line(ax,Lines(next_line,[1 3]),Lines(next_line,[2 4]),'LineWidth',4','Color',[ 1,1,1 ],'Tag','tmpline');
            end
            current_sol_idx=IpairiIdx1{current_line}(current_l_next_p_idx);
            current_p_idx = find(IpairiIdx1{next_line}==current_sol_idx);
            current_line=next_line;
            current_point=SortIntr{current_line}(current_p_idx,:);
            current_nrm=norm(current_point-ipoint);
            current_o=atan2d(-current_point(2)+ipoint(2),current_point(1)-ipoint(1));

            sol_idx_list(end+1)=current_sol_idx; %#ok<SAGROW>
            point_list(end+1,:)=current_point; %#ok<SAGROW>
            line_list(end+1)=current_line;
            if DRAW_DEBUG,line(ax,current_point(1),current_point(2),'LineStyle','none','Marker','O','MarkerSize',12,'Color','m','tag','tmppoint');end %draw intersection points
            %select between two options. next clockwise point is the one with higher angle
            if current_p_idx+1<=length(SortIntr{current_line}) && current_p_idx-1>0
                next_point_1=SortIntr{current_line}(current_p_idx+1,:);
                next_point_2=SortIntr{current_line}(current_p_idx-1,:);
                if norm(next_point_1-ipoint)<NORM_EPS
                    current_l_next_p_idx=current_p_idx+1;
                elseif norm(next_point_2-ipoint)<NORM_EPS
                    current_l_next_p_idx=current_p_idx-1;
                else
                    o1=atan2d(-next_point_1(2)+ipoint(2),next_point_1(1)-ipoint(1));
                    o2=atan2d(-next_point_2(2)+ipoint(2),next_point_2(1)-ipoint(1));
                    if o1>o2
                        current_l_next_p_idx=current_p_idx+1;
                    else
                        current_l_next_p_idx=current_p_idx-1;
                    end
                end
            elseif current_p_idx-1>0
                current_l_next_p_idx=current_p_idx-1;
            else
                current_l_next_p_idx=current_p_idx+1;
            end

            next_p=SortIntr{current_line}(current_l_next_p_idx,:);
            next_o=atan2d(-next_p(2)+ipoint(2),next_p(1)-ipoint(1));
            next_nrm=norm(next_p-ipoint);
            if DRAW_DEBUG,disp([current_nrm,next_nrm,current_o,next_o]);end
            next_line=AllPairs(IpairiIdx1{current_line}(current_l_next_p_idx), IpairiIdx2{current_line}(current_l_next_p_idx));
            next_sol_idx=IpairiIdx1{current_line}(current_l_next_p_idx);
            if VisitedSequence(current_sol_idx,next_sol_idx)
                next_line=-2;
                if DRAW_DEBUG,disp('seq visited');end
                break;
            end
            if next_nrm>NORM_EPS && next_o<current_o || next_o-current_o>180
                next_line=-2;
                if DRAW_DEBUG,disp('next_o<current_o');end
                break; %non clockwise
            end
            assert(next_nrm<NORM_EPS && next_line==iline || next_nrm>=NORM_EPS && next_line~=iline);
        end

        if next_line==iline
            sol_idx_list(end+1)=next_sol_idx; %#ok<SAGROW>
            point_list(end+1,:)=next_p; %#ok<SAGROW>
            PointsInPartition{end+1}=point_list; %#ok<SAGROW>
            SolIndexInPartition{end+1}=sol_idx_list; %#ok<SAGROW>
            %Line4PointsInPartition{end+1}=(Lines(AllPairs(sol_idx_list,1),:), [1; 0])+kron(Lines(AllPairs(sol_idx_list,2),:), [0; 1]);%#ok<SAGROW>
            Line4PointsInPartition{end+1}=Lines(line_list,:);%#ok<SAGROW>

            for i=1:length(sol_idx_list)-1
                VisitedSequence(sol_idx_list(i),sol_idx_list(i+1))=true;
            end
            count_added=count_added+1;
        else
            count_skipped=count_skipped+1;
        end
        if DRAW_DEBUG, disp([next_line==iline, count_added,count_skipped]);end
    end
end

% draw all segments
if DRAW_DEBUG %clear debug
    delete(findall(ax,'Tag','tmppoint'));
    delete(findall(ax,'Tag','tmpline'));
end
NPartition=length(PointsInPartition);
s=sprintf('Lines=%d, Segments=%d, RunTime=%1.2fsec',NLines,NPartition,toc);
title(ax,s);
fprintf([s,newline]);
if DRAW_FINAL_POLY
    hold(ax,'on');
    for i=1:NPartition
        plist=PointsInPartition{i};
        patch(plist(:,1),plist(:,2),i,'FaceAlpha',.3)
        [cx,cy]=ploygon_centroid(plist(:,1),plist(:,2));
        if(DRAW_FINALTEXT),text(cx,cy,sprintf('%d',i),'FontSize',12,'Color','k');end
    end
end

function [px,py,isok,d] = LineIntersection(Line1, Line2)
    %Line1=[x1,y1,x2,y2] Line2=[x3,y3,x4,y4]
    x1=Line1(:,1); y1=Line1(:,2); x2=Line1(:,3); y2=Line1(:,4);
    x3=Line2(:,1); y3=Line2(:,2); x4=Line2(:,3); y4=Line2(:,4);
    d=(x1-x2).*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2).*(x3-x4);%determinant
    px0=(x1.*y2-y1.*x2).*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2).*(x3.*y4-y3.*x4);
    py0=(x1.*y2-y1.*x2).*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2).*(x3.*y4-y3.*x4);
    isok=abs(d)>1e-6;
    px=px0./d;
    py=py0./d;
end

function [xc,yc] = ploygon_centroid(x,y)
    xs = circshift(x,-1);
    ys = circshift(y,-1);
    area = 0.5*sum (x.*ys-xs.*y);
    xc = sum((x.*ys-xs.*y).*(x+xs))/(6*area);
    yc = sum((x.*ys-xs.*y).*(y+ys))/(6*area);
end
```

[image: Result of random 5 lines]
[image: 8 lines]

Comment: This is really nice and works well, but I'm really looking for a list of sets. This script labels them nicely and is clearly able to identify them, but how do I go about retrieving a list of the sets that are labelled?

Comment: Fixed some bugs. I added the lines that participate in partition in variable 'Line4PointsInPartition'

Comment: @Piinthesky No, I’m interested in the unbounded ones as well.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** New solution, using itertools. Old solution below.
Using the python package `itertools`, I believe this solution is faster than the original. However, it is still extremely slow and is not feasible beyond about 20-ish lines. For 120 lines, none of these will terminate.

```python
import itertools

strings = ["<=", ">="]

fxs = ["5x + 3", "-60x + 7", ...]

parts = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(len(fxs))
    out = itertools.product(strings, repeat=len(fxs))
    for i in out:
        curpart = ""
        for j in range(len(i)):
            print(curpart)
            if j != len(i):
                curpart = curpart + "y " + i[j] + fxs[j] + " && "
            else:
                curpart = curpart + "y " + i[j] + fxs[j]
        parts.append(curpart)
    print(parts)
```

**OLD SOLUTION**

Here's what ended up working for me, in python:

```python
fxs = [list of functions as strings, ex: "5x+3","6x+4"... etc.]

parts = []


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for f in fxs:
        fhalf = "y >= " + f
        shalf = "y <= " + f
        if len(parts) == 0:
            parts.append(fhalf)
            parts.append(shalf)
        else:
            parts1 = [s + " && " + fhalf for s in parts]
            parts2 = [s + " && " + shalf for s in parts]
            parts = parts1 + parts2
    print(parts)
```

For the above example, this outputs:

```
['y >= 5x+3 && y >= 90x+7 && y >= -30x+28 && y >= 60x+2', 'y <= 5x+3 && y >= 90x+7 && y >= -30x+28 && y >= 60x+2', 'y >= 5x+3 && y <= 90x+7 && y >= -30x+28 && y >= 60x+2', 'y <= 5x+3 && y <= 90x+7 && y >= -30x+28 && y >= 60x+2', 'y >= 5x+3 && y >= 90x+7 && y <= -30x+28 && y >= 60x+2', 'y <= 5x+3 && y >= 90x+7 && y <= -30x+28 && y >= 60x+2', 'y >= 5x+3 && y <= 90x+7 && y <= -30x+28 && y >= 60x+2', 'y <= 5x+3 && y <= 90x+7 && y <= -30x+28 && y >= 60x+2', 'y >= 5x+3 && y >= 90x+7 && y >= -30x+28 && y <= 60x+2', 'y <= 5x+3 && y >= 90x+7 && y >= -30x+28 && y <= 60x+2', 'y >= 5x+3 && y <= 90x+7 && y >= -30x+28 && y <= 60x+2', 'y <= 5x+3 && y <= 90x+7 && y >= -30x+28 && y <= 60x+2', 'y >= 5x+3 && y >= 90x+7 && y <= -30x+28 && y <= 60x+2', 'y <= 5x+3 && y >= 90x+7 && y <= -30x+28 && y <= 60x+2', 'y >= 5x+3 && y <= 90x+7 && y <= -30x+28 && y <= 60x+2', 'y <= 5x+3 && y <= 90x+7 && y <= -30x+28 && y <= 60x+2']
```

The code is extremely simple and the output is exactly as desired.

The idea is basically that each line divides the plane into two halves, and so the loop (which iterates over the set of lines) intersects each partition already found with each half and adds the two new partitions to the set, while removing the original, in-intersected partition. The result doesn't always give the simplest possible condition (some of the conditions may be redundant), but they do give a complete description of each partition.

While this solution works, with 120 lines, it is pretty slow. I'd be interested in seeing if there are more efficient ways to accomplish this, using this method or otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't work properly, does it? You don't look at the relation between lines (e.g. all go through (0, 0) or all are parallel), to make a sound judgement. Even if no special conditions: You also don't get all subsets with your strategy, e.g. two lines produce in your script only three partitions.

Comment: Yes, I have come to realize that it doesn't actually work as intended. The original script worked, but the new one does not. I have updated the answer with a new solution that does work, but is still extremely slow.

Comment: I am talking about the `itertools` program. It has the flaws mentioned above. Try it with two lines.

Comment: With the fix, the itertools code works, for upto 20-ish lines. After that it is too slow to be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to those suggested so far would be to work with triangles.

Start with a set of triangles (which may contain points at infinity) whose union is a polygon covering the full plane. For instance, you can start which the four triangles resulting for partitioning the plane with the first two lines given as input to the algorithm or taking the three triangles formed by the origin O, the positive side of the OX axis, and the two semi-lines forming 120 and 240 degrees with OX and also starting at O.

Now, for every line given as input you go looking for the triangles it crosses and for every one of those, you cut it at the intersection with the line and get it replaced by three (or two in degenerated cases) new triangles covering the same area. Then you have to find the polygons those old intersected triangles were part of, and replace every one of then by the two polygons resulting of splitting the triangles it contains depending on the side of the line they lay on.

The good thing about using triangles is that it makes calculations much easier, and that you can push then in some indexing data structure such as a k-d tree which would make much faster calculating which polygons are cut by some line, and you may end with an algorithm which complexity O(NlogN) where N is the number of polygons forming the plane partition.